# Capture-recapture analysis with only one recapture event

Tags: survival, model, capture-mark-recapture

I am analyzing within-season variation of the components of reproductive success looking at temporal changes and their relationship. I have a problem with pre-fledging survival (the survival probability from hatch to the time of banding in late summer, shortly before fledging). Conventional capture-recapture methods cannot be used to estimate pre-fledging survival because it requires at least two recapture events and after marking young at the nest with web-tags we only have one recapture event (one month later during banding).

I have some information available that I can use such as: estimate the partial brood loss (i.e. broods in which at least one individual survives to banding) and total brood loss (when no individuals survive). Because young remain together with their parents, mortality due to partial brood loss can be estimated based on the recapture of web-tagged young at banding by the difference between the number of young recaptured that belong to a particular family/nest and the original value for this brood. This will allow us to see how many young are missing. Total brood loss can be estimated by combining young:adult ratio in our captures at banding with the average brood size independently estimated during field observation at that time, and assuming that all families have two adults. According to hatching date, there will be two groups of pre-fledging survival (before and after the median hatch date).

I really appreciate any help/input.